# How to determine if an object is some type of KeyValue<,> pair without using reflection

Tags: c#, object, types

I need to determine if an object is of some type of KeyValue pair.  It is not important for me to know which types are used for the key or the value.  So: `

```
public bool IsKeyValuePair (object o)
{
    //What code should go here?
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729614/c-sharp-reflection-how-can-i-tell-if-object-o-is-of-type-keyvaluepair-and-then) describes how to determine this using reflection, however in my case I am processing 100s of thousands of objects and it is creating a bottleneck in my app.

Perhaps there is a way to do it with a Try / Catch block or something?

Comment: You can't.  If you want to do this then reflection is how it is done.  You can cache the results for improved performance, but you need reflection to get the results in the first place.

Comment: Surely there is some outside of the box workaround..for example, could you somehow cast they key and the value to KeyValuePair<object,object> inside a try/catch block or something similar?

Comment: No, you can't.  If you have a `KeyValuePair<int, string>` for instance you can't cast it to `KeyValuePair<object, object>` - that's why you need reflection.  If you need to extract the key and value from an arbitrary `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` instance you'll have to use reflection at least once, even if you're building expression trees etc.  If you don't know what the type is at compile time you have to use reflection at runtime.  Period.

Comment: How many distinct types are in those 100s of thousands objects? Caching that @Corey suggested could be a viable strategy

Comment: What are you going to _do_ if it _is_ a key value pair? You obviously don't know the compile time type so what can you do at runtime without reflection?

Comment: alexm - Probably not too many so yes, catching some specific ones could also be a solution.

Comment: I treat the various bits of data differently depending on whether they are a keyvalue pair or a non-key value pair.  I don't always need to know what the key value pair is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Original Objects from your source code
            var myKeyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("HELLO", "THERE");
            var notKeyValuePar = "HELLO THERE";

            // This is so we don't know what it is.
            object o1 = myKeyValuePair;
            object o2 = notKeyValuePar;

            // TEST with a KeyValuePair
            if (IsKeyValuePair(o1))
                Console.WriteLine("o1 is KeyValuePair");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("o1 is NOT KeyValuePair");

            // TEST with a string
            if (IsKeyValuePair(o2))
                Console.WriteLine("o2 is KeyValuePair");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("o2 is NOT KeyValuePair");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static private bool IsKeyValuePair(Object o)
        {
            return String.Compare(o.GetType().Name.ToString(), "KeyValuePair`2") == 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If all you ever want to know is whether or not it *is* a `KeyValuePair<,>` then you do this: `o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)`.  But that's reflection.

Comment: This does seem to be a correct answer (and a very comprehensive one at that).  Corey, that reflection will error if it's not a generic type, so you first need to check "o.GetType().IsGenericType".  That extra step could be what slows it down.

Anyway, I did a test and it seems that Robert's solution is at least twice as fast than the reflection code I was using and works for all of my test cases so far.   So I think that this deserves to be the accepted answer.

Comment: Robert, thank you very much for your answer.  I think String.Compare is a little slower than a direct comparison (as it considers culture etc), so to get a little more efficiency, I am using:

return (o != null && o.GetType().Name == "KeyValuePair`2");