# How to iterate through an enumeration of KeyValuePair without knowing the type of the key and the type of the value

Tags: c#

Say I have a method like this:

```
public void Foo(object arguments)
```

and say I need to detect if the type of `arguments` is actually an enumeration. I would write something like this:

```
if (arguments is IEnumerable)
```

Now, let's say I need to detect if it's an enumeration of KeyValuePair (regardless of the type of the key and the type of the value). My instinct would be to write something like this:

```
if (arguments is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>)
```

but visual studio complains that `Using the generic type 'KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments`.

I also tried:

```
if (arguments is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>)
```

but it returns false if the key is anything but an object (such as a `string` for example) or if the value is anything but an object (such as an `int` for example).

Does anybody have suggestions how I could determine if an enumeration contains KeyValuePairs regardless of the key type and the value type and if so, how can I loop through these pairs?

Comment: Just in case this is a XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you tell us the underlying issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: _"Does anybody have suggestions how I could determine if an enumeration contains KeyValuePairs regardless of the key type and the value type?"_ -- the obvious option is reflection. But your question is unclear, and shows no evidence of research or attempting anything productive. C# doesn't support open generic types, as you've found...the type needs to be known at compile-time. So, even if you did identify that the enumeration contained `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` instances, what would you do with them? Please improve your question so that it's clear what the goal and constraints here are.

Comment: You could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2729671/6741868), it describes a method of checking using reflection.

Comment: @mjwills The `Foo` method is part of a library and developers invoke it (I don't have the liberty of changing the signature of this method). The method must detect the type of `arguments` and perform different logic depending on type. One case is when it's an enumeration of KeyValuePair but I'm struggling to figure out how to detect this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some reflection here:

```
Boolean isKeyValuePair = false;

Type type = arguments.GetType();

if (type.IsGenericType)
{
    Type[] genericTypes = type.GetGenericArguments();

    if (genericTypes.Length == 1)
    {
        Type underlyingType = genericTypes[0];

        if (underlyingType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))
            isKeyValuePair = true;
    }
}
```

In order to rebuild an `Enumerable` and iterate over it, you could use the following approach that uses `dynamic`:

```
List<KeyValuePair<Object, Object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<Object, Object>>();

foreach (dynamic kvp in (IEnumerable)arguments)
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<Object, Object>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
```

or, with `LINQ`:

```
List<KeyValuePair<Object, Object>> list = (from dynamic kvp in (IEnumerable)arguments select new KeyValuePair<Object, Object>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToList();
```

I also found another solution, but this is pure madness:

```
Boolean isKeyValuePair = false;

Type type = arguments.GetType();

if (type.IsGenericType)
{
    Type[] genericTypes = type.GetGenericArguments();

    if (genericTypes.Length == 1)
    {
        Type underlyingType = genericTypes[0];

        if (underlyingType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (KeyValuePair<,>))
        {
            Type[] kvpTypes = underlyingType.GetGenericArguments();

            Type kvpType = typeof(KeyValuePair<,>);
            kvpType = kvpType.MakeGenericType(kvpTypes);

            Type listType = typeof (List<>);
            listType = listType.MakeGenericType(kvpType);

            dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

            foreach (dynamic argument in (IEnumerable)arguments)
                list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(kvpType, argument.Key, argument.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- [Type.IsGenericType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Type.GetGenericArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This looks very good. I'll test right away. Once we have determined that the enumeration contains KeyValue pairs, do you have suggestion on how to loop through the items?

Comment: Do you want to cast it? Because if you just want to know the key and value types you can use `Type[] kvTypes = typeDefinition.GetGenericArguments();`. Let me do a check on how to see how to proceed using the best approach.

Comment: Actually... this is getting unclear. Your `arguments` is supposed to be what? A list ok KeyValuePair? A Dictionary? Mixed data?

Comment: Oooooooook I edited my answer. I found a way to rebuild a generic `Enumerable` of `KeyValuePair<Object, Object>` using `dynamic`.

Comment: Your idea to use dynamic is genius! Let me try it right away

Comment: I added a brand new solution... but I think we are going too far here...

Comment: @desautelsj this is a good answer. however i think you need to update your question with a minimal example method to describe what you want (even if its semi pseudo code) but please give input parameters and return type. like we need to have some idea of what you are trying to achieve with what initial types

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection with `GetGenericTypeDefinition`

```
var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("asd", 123);

var isOf = pair.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>);
```

*Note : It will throw an exception if it isn't a generic type*

```
InvalidOperationException
```

> The current type is not a generic type. That is, IsGenericType returns
>   false.

You can check this with `Type.IsGenericType`

I'm not sure really want you want to achieve here however,

**Some nonsensical examples in a `foreach`**

```
private bool Get<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Type someType) 
{
   foreach (var item in list)
   {
      if (item.GetType()
               .GetGenericTypeDefinition() == someType)
      {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}

private List<T> Get2<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Type someType)
{
   return list.Where(
         item => item.GetType()
                     .GetGenericTypeDefinition() == someType)
      .ToList();
}}
```

**Usage**

```
var blah = Get2(list, typeof(KeyValuePair<,>));
```

> **Note** : All this really depends on what you want to do, its hard to
>   tell, both of these above are only silly examples of not knowing the
>   type beforehand, and may not work for what you want.

**Additional information**

[Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Type.IsGenericType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Looks good! Do you have suggestion on how to loop through this enumeration of KeyValue pairs (keeping in mind that we don't know the type of Key and Value)?

Comment: @desautelsj Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @tommaso-belluzzo and @sarumanfor for investing the time to help me figure this out. I ended up accepting Tommaso's answer because I really like his idea of using the `dynamic` type to enumerate items in the enumeration.

I also wanted to contribute my solution (which is largely based on Tommasso's suggestions)

```
/// <summary>Get the key=>value pairs represented by a dictionary, enumeration of KeyValue pairs or an anonymous object.</summary>
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetArguments(object arguments)
{
    // null
    if (arguments == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    // dictionary
    if (arguments is IDictionary dictionary)
        return dictionary
            .Cast<dynamic>()
            .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value));

    // enumeration
    if (arguments is IEnumerable enumeration)
    {
#if NETFULL
        var argumentsType = enumeration.GetType();
        var itemType = argumentsType.GetElementType();
        var isGeneric = itemType.IsGenericType;
        var enumeratedType = isGeneric ? itemType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : null;
#else
        var argumentsTypeInfo = enumeration.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
        var itemTypeInfo = argumentsTypeInfo.GetElementType().GetTypeInfo();
        var isGeneric = itemTypeInfo.IsGenericType;
        var enumeratedType = isGeneric ? itemTypeInfo.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : null;
#endif

        if (enumeratedType == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))
        {
            return enumeration
                .Cast<dynamic>()
                .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("You must provide an enumeration of KeyValuePair", nameof(arguments));
        }
    }

    // object
    return arguments.GetType()
        .GetRuntimeProperties()
        .Where(p => p.CanRead)
        .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Name, p.GetValue(arguments)));
}
```