# How to get value from a KeyValuePair<> with unknown type

Tags: c#, reflection, keyvaluepair

I have an object that is a KeyValuePair<> whose types I do not know. I need to get the Value of this KeyValuePair as object.

```
object kvpair = ... ;         // This is a KeyValuePair<K, V> with unknown K and V.
object value = kvpair.Value;  // I want to get the value of the kvpair
```

I understand this will involve using reflection.

Comment: Then from where you are getting?

Comment: Will `dynamic` help?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mre].

Comment: Do you want to know type of the 'value' in in KeyValuePair?

Comment: @Sibgath No, I only need the value as object

Comment: Will this work: `object value = (KeyValuePair<object, object>)kvpair.Value;`?

Comment: @Stefan No, you can't cast KeyValuePair<K, V> into KeyValuePair<object, object>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the following topic. You will find more than you need there: [C# Reflection - How can I tell if object o is of type KeyValuePair and then cast it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729614/c-sharp-reflection-how-can-i-tell-if-object-o-is-of-type-keyvaluepair-and-then)

LE:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value");
Type aux = kvp.GetType();
object kvpValue = aux.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(kvp, null);
Console.WriteLine(kvpValue);
```